# psycopg2 - insert into variable coumns using extras.batch_execution

Tags: python, pandas

I am inserting a pandas dataframe into postgres using psycopg2.
Below code:

```
...
import psycopg2.extras as extras

tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
cols = ','.join(list(column_list))
query  = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES (%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s)" % (table  , cols)

extras.execute_batch(cursor, query, tuples, page_size = 100)
...
```

This works!

Here, I convert df into tuple, and I think **%%s** is taking this values at runtime when extras.execute_batch is executed.

The problem is that for this, I need to hardcode **%%s**, number of times the columns.

In this example its 5 columns, hence I am using `%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s`.

Is there a way to have it variable?

Here is what I tried:

```
...
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
cols = ','.join(list(column_list))

vals_frame = len(column_list) * """%%s,"""
vals_frame = vals_frame[:-1]
print('vals_frame: ',vals_frame)
query  = query  = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES("+vals_frame+")" % (table  , cols)

extras.execute_batch(cursor, query, tuples, page_size = 100)
...
```

This prints:

```
vals_frame: '%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s'
```

which is what I want, but I get below error while creation of query:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

How to get past this?

I have tried:

```
vals_frame = len(column_list) * """\%\%s,"""
vals_frame = len(column_list) * """\\%%s,"""
```

but this does not seem to work. Can some one help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the location of the %.  Because of operator precedence, % binds tighter than +.  So:

```
query  = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES("+vals_frame+")" % (table  , cols)
```

The `%` operator here applies to the string ")".  Here are some alternatives to consider:

```
query  = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES(" % (table, cols) +vals_frame+")"
query  = ("INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES("+vals_frame+")") % (table  , cols)
query  = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES(%s)" % (table, cols, vals_frame)
```

Alternatively, avoid the problem by using f-strings:

```
query  = f"INSERT INTO {table}({cols}) VALUES({vals_frame});"
```